# ¿Como restringir el valor de una columna con respecto a otra en una tabla en SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguente tabla:

```
Clientes (
    Nombre varchar(50) not null,
    Id_Cliente varchar(15) primary key,
    Telefono varchar(15) not null unique,
    Edad int not null,
    Email varchar(50) not null unique,
    Deudor bit not null default 0,
    Deuda real not null default 0
    constraint CK_VALIDACION_EDAD check (Edad >= 18)
)
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que la columna "Deuda" solo admita datos mayores que cero si la columna "Deudor" es diferente de cero.¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `constraint` adecuado para verificar lo que pides debiera ser algo así:

```
CONSTRAINT check_Deuda CHECK ((Deudor = 1) or (Deudor = 0 and Deuda = 0))
```

Por ejemplo:

```
create table Clientes (
    Nombre varchar(50) not null,
    Id_Cliente varchar(15) primary key,
    Telefono varchar(15) not null unique,
    Edad int not null,
    Email varchar(50) not null unique,
    Deudor bit not null default 0,
    Deuda real not null default 0,
    constraint CK_VALIDACION_EDAD check (Edad >= 18),
    CONSTRAINT check_Deuda CHECK ((Deudor = 1) or (Deudor = 0 and Deuda = 0))
)

-- No deudor con Deuda -> Error
insert into Clientes (Nombre, Id_Cliente, Telefono, Edad, Email, Deudor, Deuda) 
values ('cliente 1', 1, '', 19, '', 0, 100);

-- No deudor sin Deuda -> Ok
insert into Clientes (Nombre, Id_Cliente, Telefono, Edad, Email, Deudor, Deuda) 
values ('cliente 2', 2, '', 19, '', 0, 0);

-- Deudor con Deuda -> Ok
insert into Clientes (Nombre, Id_Cliente, Telefono, Edad, Email, Deudor, Deuda) 
values ('cliente 3', 3, '', 19, '', 1, 100);

-- Deudor sin  Deuda -> Ok
insert into Clientes (Nombre, Id_Cliente, Telefono, Edad, Email, Deudor, Deuda) 
values ('cliente 4', 4, '', 19, '', 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar un constraint a tu tabla sobre el campo Deuda, indicando la condición que citas en tu pregunta, de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE Clientes (
    Nombre varchar(50) not null,
    Id_Cliente varchar(15) primary key,
    Telefono varchar(15) not null unique,
    Edad int not null,
    Email varchar(50) not null unique,
    Deudor bit not null default 0,
    Deuda real not null default 0,
    constraint CK_VALIDACION_EDAD check (Edad >= 18),
    constraint CK_VALIDACION_Deuda check ((Deuda >= 0) and Deudor != 0)
)

--Ejemplo con deudor igual 0
INSERT INTO Clientes Values ('Delcio', '00115252362', '102-320-3202', 18, 'programador@gmail.com', 0, 1500);
--Ejemplo con deudor igual mayor a 0
INSERT INTO Clientes Values ('Delcio', '00115252362', '102-320-3202', 18, 'programador@gmail.com', 1, 1500);
```

Para ver el ejemplo en vivo visualiza el siguiente [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c8da/1)